# Erro de navegação com React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-router

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em React Native com tres tipos de navegações: Drawer, Bottom Tab e Stack Navigator. Eu inseri esses tres tipos de navegação porém mostra o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele fala que tenho dois "NavigationContainer" porém só existe um na minha aplicação. Alguem sabe o que posso fazer nesse caso? Segue código abaixo:

```
function Drawer(){
return(
    <AppDrawer.Navigator
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
    drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#0e28cc'
    }}
    drawerContentOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        activeTintColor: '#fff',
        inactiveTintColor: '#ddd',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#0e9dcc',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#0e9dcc',
        itemStyle: {
            marginVertical: 5
        }

    }}
    >
        <AppDrawer.Screen name="Editar Perfil" component={EditPerfil} />
    </AppDrawer.Navigator>
)
```

}

```
function Tabs(){
return(
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => {
            const {} = icons[route.name];
            return <Icon name={name} color={color} size={size} />
        }
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#121212'
        },
        activeTintColor: '#fff',
    }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Formulário" component={Form}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Perfil" component={Perfil}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
)
```

}

```
export default function AppRoutes(){
return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Editar Perfil" component={Drawer} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

}

Comment: Você instalou a biblioteca react-natvigation e fez o import corretamente? import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

Comment: Sim, está instalado e o import está correto.